# Hadoop HDFS is not distributing blocks of data evenly

Tags: hadoop, filesystems, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am currently running a cluster with 2 nodes. 1 Node is master/slave and the other one is just slave. I have a file and I set the block size to half the size of that file. Then I do

`hdfs dfs -put file /`

File gets copied to the HDFS no problem, but when I check the HDFS site, I see that both the blocks that was created is in one datanode (the blocks are on the datanode whereI used the -put command). I even tried to call the balancer script but both the blocks are still on the same datanode.

I need the data to be evenly spread out (as much as possible) between all nodes.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What says `hdfs dfs -ls /file` ?

Comment: File will be a plain text file. I'm not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: You are indeed misunderstanding my question. Let me rephrase it. Can you post the result of the command `hdfs dfs -ls /file`?

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, I just got to work. But here is what you requested.

bash-4.1$ hdfs dfs -ls /input/data1.txt
15/03/09 08:51:29 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
-rw-r--r--   1 blahblah supergroup        390 2015-03-06 16:57 /input/data1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `hdfs dfs -ls` output shows, your replication factor is set to `1`, so there is no compelling reason for `hdfs` to distribute the data blocks on the datanodes.

You need to increase the replication level to at least `2` to get what you expect, eg:

```
hdfs dfs -setrep 2 /input/data1.txt
```

Comment: Is this essentially the same as changing dfs.replication to 2 in hdfs-site.xml?

Comment: The command I suggested will do it just for that file while yours will impact all the files on that filesystem.

Comment: Just curious, is there a way to have the hdfs distribute the blocks without having it replicate? for example, node 1 will only contain half the block and node 2 will contain the rest of the block, assuming I set block size to half the input file size.

Comment: The default behavior is to store all blocks on the same server as the writer (see https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/blockmanagement/BlockPlacementPolicyDefault.java ). You might implement your own policy to achieve your distribution goal.

Answer (score 0):

when we are writing data into hdfs, to save bandwidth utilization and network round trips initial copy is trying to save on the same node where we are executing hadoop put command. As your replication 1 , it happens like that.