# hdfs moveFromLocal does not distribute replica blocks across data nodes

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, replication, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

I recently upgraded my Cloudera environment from 5.8.x (*hadoop 2.6.0, hdfs-1*) to 6.3.x (*hadoop 3.0.0, hdfs-1*) and after some days of data loads with `moveFromLocal`, i just realized that the ***DFS Used%*** of datanode server on which i execute `moveFromLocal` are 3x more than that of others.

Then having run `fsck` with `-blocks`, `-locations` and `-replicaDetails` flags over the hdfs path to which i load the data; i observed that replicated blocks (RF=2) are **all** on that same server and not being distributed to other nodes unless i manually run `hdfs balancer`.

There is a pertinent question asked a month ago,
[hdfs put/moveFromLocal not distributing data across data nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59363801/hdfs-put-movefromlocal-not-distributing-data-across-data-nodes), which does not really answer any of the questions; the files i keep loading are parquet files.

There was no such a problem in the Cloudera 5.8.x. Is there some new configuration should i make in Cloudera 6.3.x related to replication, rack awareness or something like that?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I didnt know it is possible to have more than 1 replica of a block on the same datanode. Can you double check that?

Comment: Yes it is possible if you distribute them across separate disks on a server, and , not sure but may reside on the same disk if you have lesser datanodes than the RF, which is against the purpose of replication whatsoever. But, what i meant there and my case is totally different; which is, whereas original blocks (primaries) are distributed across all the datanodes, replicas (secondaries) of each block of loaded data are on the server where i run the loading operation, that is moveFromLocal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [HDFS Architecture](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsDesign.html#Replica_Placement:_The_First_Baby_Steps) doc, *"For the common case, when the replication factor is three, HDFS’s placement policy is to put one replica on the local machine if the writer is on a datanode..."*

Per the same doc, *"Because the **NameNode does not allow DataNodes to have multiple replicas of the same block**, maximum number of replicas created is the total number of DataNodes at that time."*

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, this was really helpful, i realized that i was executing moveFromLocal from a gateway node in the old cluster, therefore replicas were not put on that local machine, being distributed instead.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably doing moveFromLocal on one of your datanodes. Seems like you need to do your moveFromLocal from non-datanode to get even distribution on your cluster.